# GraphPlot3D with weights for similarity and self connections

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I want to use GraphPlot3D, to vizualize some networks. The network edges have weights though, so I want the points with higher weights, to be closer together. 
Furthermore, a network unit can have a connection to itself. If I use GraphPlot3d, it considers none of these points automatically, so how (if it is even possible) can I tell Mathematica, to consider these both requierements.

Comment: So it is not really possible, but even with Mathematica10 ?

Comment: Check my answer in the linked thread. It is possible since version 9.